# When implementing a bean with the @Dependent annotation, 2 constructor calls occur

Tags: java, cdi

Why is this happening? Must the call occur 1 time? If I use @RequestScoped, then everything happens as usual and the constructor is called 1 time.

```java
@WebServlet(value = "/tes")
public class MyTag extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    MyBean myBean;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        
    }
}


@Model
@Dependent
class MyBean {
    public MyBean() {
        System.out.println("construct");
    }
    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstructMethod() {
        System.out.println("post constructing");
    }
}
```